# sleroy SonarEsLintPlugin EsLint Custom Rules

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sleroy/SonarEsLintPlugin plugin to integrate eslint with sonarqube v6.7.2. I have these three other eslint plugins that I want to integrate into sonarqube v.6.7.2.
A. redux-saga
B. react
C. jsx-a11y

and below is my sonar-project.propeties file:

```
sonar.projectKey=abc
sonar.projectName=xyz
sonar.projectVersion=0.0.0.1
sonar.sources=app/
sonar.exclusions= app/utils/**/*,  
sonar.language=js  
sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=.js,.jsx  
sonar.profile=ReactJs  
sonar.eslint.eslintpath=node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js  
sonar.eslint.eslintconfigpath=package.json  
sonar.eslint.eslintrulesdir=react,redux-saga,jsx-a11y  
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8  
sonar.login=pqr  
sonar.password=jkl
```

These three plugins rules are specified on eslint-rules.properties file and it is showing these rules on sonarqube also.
but the problem here is that sonarqube is not generating any report related to these three rules even I have intentionally made a mistake.

can anyine please check whether I have specified "sonar.eslint.eslintrulesdir" path right or I am missing something.
Please help me with this I am into this issue since past 3 days.